# Why while(scanf("%lld", &num) == 1) is faster than while(scanf("%lld", &num))

Tags: c++

I have tried to solve a problem from Uva Online Judge. Problem number is 10302. My accepted code is given below.

```
 #include <cstdio>

 int main()
 {
     long long int num, sum;

     while(scanf("%lld", &num) == 1)  {

        //sumOfCube(sum, num);
        //sum = (long long int)(num * num * (num + 1) * (num + 1)) / 4;
        printf("%lld\n", ((num * num) * ((num + 1) * (num + 1))) / 4);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

And Here my time limit exceeded code

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    long long int num, sum;


    while(scanf("%lld", &num))  {

        //sumOfCube(sum, num);
        //sum = (long long int)(num * num * (num + 1) * (num + 1)) / 4;
        printf("%lld\n", ((num * num) * ((num + 1) * (num + 1))) / 4);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The only difference is

```
 while(scanf("%lld", &num) == 1)
```

And

```
 while(scanf("%lld", &num))
```

I think second one is faster. Because first one add extra operator `==` to check equality. Here Right hand side already `true (1)` and when `scanf()` takes an input then Left hand side is `true`. If both side is `true` then the `while` loop is true. I think it is an extra time loss.

But i can't understand why judge choose first one is faster.

Any one please explain it.

Comment: Doesn't `scanf` return -1 on error, making your check technically wrong for the second version of the loop?

Comment: @MadPhysicist is right. The comparisons themselves have negligible time differences, but because `scanf` hits EOF, it always returns -1, meaning you get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Given @DrewMcGowen's comment, the close vote should be retracted. This is a legitimate question that can be properly reproduced. Nice teaser. I didn't make that final connection myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your second version has an *infinite loop*.**

[`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) returns `EOF` (probably a macro for `-1`, though this depends on your system to some degree) when it runs out of input, and this return value is satisfying your very loose condition.

Your rationalisation about the second one being "faster" because you didn't write `== 1` makes no sense (C++ is not executed one source code character at a time!), and this is a good example of why you should prefer to *understand the logic* rather than spending all your time attempting to micro-optimise instead.

Next time put some debug output in your code, or run your program through a debugger. You'll very quickly see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i understand it.